# Aggregation in SQL or app server?

Tags: sql

I have daily data of metrics, for a number of different entities. Would it be more efficient to store my data with cumulative values, knowing I'll have to calculate the difference to find the discrete value change for each data, or should I store it with discrete values and perform aggregate calculations in SQL? I'm looking at 365 rows of 100 or so columns for anywhere from 1-100 entities.

The cumulative values are more useful for me in the long run, but I do need to know the discrete value changes day to day as well.

Is it super snappy for me to do the summation in SQL for the cumulative and simply pull the data for the discrete, or should I favor the opposite?

Comment: if you only have 365 rows then I wouldn't have thought SQL on a modern server will have any problem doing aggregate functions on them

Comment: @Gar You know I hadn't thought of that actually. I have about 40,000 rows per year... doubling that isn't that big of a deal if it means reducing the complexity of the app server and its interactions with the SQL server.